# Why won't my arms dealer move into the house I built just for him and his family?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I got a notice once I acquired a musket that "Deshawn", my arms dealer, was ready to settle. I have built a house with walls, background, light source, door, chair and table and he simply will not spawn.

I haven't seen any other notice regarding him again yet. Can anyone give me any advice on what I should do?

Comment: Does the mobile version of Terraria have a way to validate housing? At least on the PC, you can get the game to tell you whether or not your house is valid or not. If it's not, there's likely a problem with your background walls. If it is, you may just need to walk sufficiently far enough away from your house for the NPC to spawn.

Comment: NPCs will usually arrive at daybreak.  If they haven't arrived yet, give them a few more days as it can sometimes take time.  Also make sure you have plenty of space in your house AND no dark areas, as well as using valid background building materials.  That should cover you for regular Terraria problems, so if it's mobile-specific, you'll have to consult elsewhere.

Comment: How big is the house?  In terms of # of interior tiles.